# How to avoid to modify the event object in this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

This question is related to this one [Autocomplete: first item focused only when the user type on tab key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039219/autocomplete-first-item-focused-only-when-the-user-type-on-tab-key).

In order to make the first item focused only when the user type on tab key by using jqueryUi  is possible to make something like this http://jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/8/ (1).

The bad thing about this implementation is the modification of the event object `event.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;`.
In fact by doing this way, it will impact all other listeners on this event: all listener on the keydown event running later (which includes all delegated listeners) will see the `event.keycode` as being `$.ui.keyCode.ENTER`.

My questions are:

1. Are my concerns about **the modification of the event object** justified? If not why?
2. Can you suggest another way to achieve the same result?
3. One opition, as suggested by @AaronDigulla, could be to use `document.createEvent()`. What is the proper way to use this method in this context? I did try the following code (3) but it does not work.

P.S.:
Here is the code about autocomplete (2).

---

(1)

```
$("#box").keydown(function(e){
    if( e.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.TAB) return;
    
   e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
   $(this).trigger(e);

   e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
   $(this).trigger(e);
    
   $(this).siblings("input").select();
});
```

---

(2)

```
function (e) {
    var f = typeof e == "string",
        g = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        h = this;
    return e = !f && g.length ? a.extend.apply(null, [!0, e].concat(g)) : e, f && e.charAt(0) === "_" ? h : (f ? this.each(function () {
        var d = a.data(this, c),
            f = d && a.isFunction(d[e]) ? d[e].apply(d, g) : d;
        if (f !== d && f !== b) return h = f, !1
    }) : this.each(function () {
        var b = a.data(this, c);
        b ? b.option(e || {})._init() : a.data(this, c, new d(e, this))
    }), h)
}
```

---

(3)

```
$("#box").keydown(function(){

    e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    e.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
    $(this).dispatchEvent(e);

    if( e.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.TAB) return;
    
   e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
   $(this).trigger(e);

   e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
   $(this).trigger(e);
    
   $(this).siblings("input").select();
});
```

Comment: Autocomplete stops the delegation of the `ENTER` keypress.  It's somewhat intentional to reuse the object as all its other properties need to be the same.  Other solutions might be to modify the js source or maybe try and call the internal autocomplete methods.

Comment: @Nal thanks for your comment. What about call the internal autocomplete methods, can you give me an exmaple?

Comment: So I dug through the autocomplete source code. You still need to have an event object to call the relevant methods. `.trigger` just does it at the highest level.  The other simplest workaround would be to just fork autocomplete and add the functionality.  The modification of the event object is fine as it won't go beyond the autocomplete event listener although you could use a new `$.Event` for each `.trigger`.

Comment: @Nal, what do you mean exactly with  `although you could use a new $.Event for each .trigger`? Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct: The event will be modified an all listeners will see the modified key code.

But the more important question is: Is this dangerous?

To answer this, we need to know which listeners are bound to the element. Surely, all the listeners from the autocomplete plugin are designed to handle this situation. For them, this is OK.

The trouble starts when you bind your own events to the widgets.

A solution would be to create new events (using `document.createEvent()` + copying all important attributes) and send the clone to avoid modifying the original event.

Some links:

- [Keyboard Events and Codes](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) (shows the fields of the events as you type)
- [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) from the Mozilla Developer Network
- [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) has helper code to create and work with events
- [Understanding Keyboard Event Data](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/dhtmlref/chap6/2/6.html) from Dynamic HTML: The Definitive Reference, 2E. Chapter 6: Scripting Events

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try to write something but it does not work: jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/18 . Can you write me few lines of code about how to use document.createEvent() ?

Comment: You will have to set all properties of the event (keyCode, charCode, target, character, ...). I've added some links to my answer.