# How to create a new Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to create new events (using `document.createEvent()` or `Jquery.Event` + copying all important attributes) and send the clone to avoid modifying the original event.
Here is the source code http://jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/20/

This question is related to this one [How to avoid to modify the event object in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041811/how-to-avoid-to-modify-the-event-object-in-this-situation/12050471#comment16095656_12050471)

Any ideas why when I type a key on my keyboard I get for `newEvent.keyCode` undefined value?

```
$("#box").keydown(function(event){

    var newEvent = $.Event("keydown");

    console.log(event.keyCode); // 68 
    console.log(newEvent.keyCode); // undefined
});
```

Comment: What makes you think that `$.Event()` will copy the existing event?

Comment: @Alnitak i'm not getting that either.. Shouldn't the ```.clone()``` function be more fitting? Or at least something like ```var newEvent = event;```?

Comment: @Luceos I would have thought `.extend()` actually - `.clone()` is for DOM elements, not arbitrary JS objects.

Comment: @Alnitak , that's correct yes. Forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery API manual](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, you can also pass an object to jQuery.Event() and its properties will be set on the newly created Event object.

So you could try `var newEvent = $.Event('keydown', event)`, but as far as I know that will only create a shallow copy of the original event object.

Alternatively just copy the properties you need:

```
var newEvent = $.Event("keydown", {
    keyCode:  event.keyCode
});
```

Unless you do that, your event object will have **no** useful properties on it at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/21/

```
var e = $.Event('keydown', en);
```

this does the effect you *(really?)* want ;)